# how to set login control to compare the credentials stored in  web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set my credential in web.config as :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20">
        <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
          <user name="Nayeem" password="pwd"></user>
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

and have my login control as :

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginEmployees" runat="server"/>
```

I want my login control to authenticate with the credentials given in the web.config file

Comment: thanks for editing dear. Actually i dont know what u people do in the text editor for tagged kind of text or for codes, can u please tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way,
Assume that you have all the areas of login control i.e. username and password

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password))
 {
  //you can set cookie
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
  //redirect when user is authenticated
  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);
 }
 else
 {
  //invalid login
 }
```

Also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142847/authentication-through-web-config-not-authenticating-in-asp-net-3-5)

Hope this helps

Myra

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
private void LoginEmployees_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(LoginEmployees.UserName, LoginEmployees.Password))
    {   
        // Valid login
        e.Authenticated = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid login
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}
```